# hide post thumbnail if there isn't a featured image

Tags: php, wordpress

i use this code to set the image in related post.
I would, if there isn't a featured image in post, to hidden the thumbnail.

my code is :

```
<div class="item">
                  <figure class="entry-image">
                      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php 
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_post_thumbnail( 'rectangle-size-small' );

                        } elseif( first_post_image() ) { // Set the first    image from the editor
                            echo '<img src="' . first_post_image() . '"     class="wp-post-image" />';
                        } ?>
                      </a>
                  </figure>
                  <header class="entry-header">
                      <h4>
                          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                      </h4>
                  </header>
            </div>
```

How i replace in line **the_post_thumbnail( 'rectangle-size-small' );**
to hidden the thumbnail ?

thanks

Comment: "hidden" is an adjective.  You want to say "to hide" both times.

Comment: sorry. Yes, i mean to hide. It's possible to hide the thumbnail ?

Answer (score 0):

The has_post_thumbnail() function checks if there is a featured image or not, therefore if there is no featured image provided, it will not be displayed.

Comment: in this case the image is displayed (an image yellow -->  'rectangle-size-small' )because i insert the code the_post_thumbnail( 'rectangle-size-small' ); What i change in this line to not show the thumbnail ?

Comment: But, as I said, this will not be displayed because if you did not set a featured image then has_post_thumbnail() will return false. I'm not really sure what you're asking but if you say that it displays the yellow image then just remove that line if you don't want it to display?